# Maven 3.6 How to resolve the latest artifact for a deployment job?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration

I've got a deployment module with its own pom.xml. I use the module to deploy a 'module' and its version.

Modules are built by bamboo and pushed into the local repository of the agent (we haven't got nexus or artifactory yet so currently using the local repo).

When it's time to deploy, I would want to pass the module name and something to fetch me the latest version in the repo.

In ivy, I can use latest.integration or latest.release. However, I am not sure why maven does not allow it or at least not anymore.

So the plan is to use the LATEST version if we don't explicitly request any version.

How would we do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: LATEST do work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, using LATEST as version would fetch the latest one.